# Error establishing a SOAP connection to a WSDL service in PHP

Tags: php, soap, types, wsdl

I am trying to connect a wsdl service. Other methods don't work without login. But when I tried the login I got a httpheaders error. My wsdl link :  http://dgpysws.teias.gov.tr/dgpys/services/EVDServis?wsdl

when i look this link= 
http://dgpysws.teias.gov.tr/dgpys/services/EVDServis.wsdl

```
<xs:element name="login">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="loginMessage" nillable="true" type="dgp:LoginMessage"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="LoginMessage">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Password" nillable="true" type="dgp:StringValue"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserName" nillable="true" type="dgp:StringValue"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Here is my php code;

```
<?php
// Turn up error reporting
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);

// Turn off WSDL caching
ini_set ('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);

$Password = 'deneeme';
$UserName = 'demnenee';

$search_query = new StdClass();
$search_query->oLoginRequest = new StdClass();
$search_query->oLoginRequest->Password = $Password;
$search_query->oLoginRequest->Username = $UserName;

echo "Setting up SOAP options\n";

$soap_options = array(
        'trace'       => 1,     // traces let us look at the actual SOAP messages later
        'exceptions'  => 1 );
$wsdl = "http://dgpysws.teias.gov.tr/dgpys/services/EVDServis?wsdl";

echo "Checking SoapClient exists\n";
echo '<br>';
if (!class_exists('SoapClient'))
{
        die ("You haven't installed the PHP-Soap module.");
}

echo "Creating webservice connection to $wsdl\n";

$webservice = new SoapClient($wsdl,$soap_options);

try {
        $result = $webservice->login($search_query);



        // perform some logic, output the data to Asterisk, or whatever you want to do with it.

} catch (SOAPFault $f) {

        // handle the fault here
        echo 'Hata:' . $f; 

}

echo "Script complete\n\n";
?>
```

I am getting this error when run php file;

> `Setting up SOAP options Checking SoapClient exists`
>   `Creating webservice connection to http://dgpysws.teias.gov.tr/dgpys/services/EVDServis?wsdl Hata:SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pmum.php:36 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('login', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pmum.php(36): SoapClient->login(Object(stdClass)) #3 {main}Script complete`

Comment: It looks as though you have inadvertently leaked a URL to a server which doesn't require authentication. I suggest you remove the URL if it contains sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://dgpysws.teias.gov.tr/dgpys/services/EVDServis.wsdl");

$p1->loginMessage->UserName->v = "Deneme";
$p1->loginMessage->Password->v = "Deneme";

$deneme = $client->login($p1);
var_dump($deneme);
```

worked for me!